# Wireshark - Only show specific protocol

Tags: wireshark

I try to only show packages with a specific protocol, e.g. only show "**TCP**".

*Optional*: I am also interested on how to exclude specific protocols, e.g. don't show **SSDP** and **NBNS**.

[image]

But I can't figure out how it works, thanks in advance for any answer!

*UPDATE*:

I tried to just use `tcp` as filter, as shown in the comment documentation link, but then the TLSv1.2, SMB2 and NBSS protocols are appearing too, instead of only TCP.

Comment: "but then the TLSv1.2, SMB2 and NBSS protocols are appearing too, instead of only TCP" – These three use TCP as a transport protocol. I think for TCP packets Wireshark shows TCP in the "Protocol" column if it cannot recognize higher level protocol. If it can, you see e.g. SMB2; this doesn't mean the packet doesn't use TCP. Research the concept of layers in networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`tcp && !ssl`

(here I'm assuming you have some browser open or some service making ssl connections, which usually happens on most of the systems)

TLS is basically SSL. [Check here for more.](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL_and_TLS_Protocols)

I think you should have a better understanding of TCP.
[Here you can find a list of common protocols](http://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1868080) running over TCP.

**Extra helpful tips:**
Create a new column for the source port:
*Right click on the columns header > Column Preferences > Click on the + sign*  and set the name to Source port and type Source port.

This way you can see what packet is being sent over TCP and over what port.

You can learn more about display filters [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters).

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you *cannot* accomplish this with something like:

```
ip.proto != "TLSv1.2"
```

If you click on the "Expression..." button next to the filter bar you can get a full list of options on how to apply filters.

My approach to filtering with Wireshark is to not *filter* solely on protocol, but the specific source/destination ports and source/destination IP addresses that the application I am troubleshooting utilizes. For instance, if I wanted to know if I am successfully reaching the remote server on TCP port 5000 I could a few things:

```
tcp.port == 5000
```

If there are lots of connections using this port, then you can drill down further by adding the target IP address and the port:

```
ip.addr == 192.0.2.1 and tcp.port == 5000
```

Can you provide me with more details on the traffic that you are trying to capture?
What is the application that you are troubleshooting?
Is there a specific source/destination IP address?
Is there a specific source/destination port?

Comment: I already managed to filter the application which I troubleshoot, but thank you very much!